# Goessner JSONPath nested filter to return sibling node

Tags: json, jsonpath

I have this skeleton JSON file and I need to filter using `externalids.system=='HQ2'` using JSONPath. I'm also using [Goessner](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/).

```
{
  "meta": {
    "numFound": 2
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "11111",
      "type": "PRODUCT_GROUP",
      "values": [
        {
          "showvalues": [
            "ObjectPosition"
          ],
          "value": "4",
          "attributeid": "gd4d20ffc-0374-4764-8b01-19b2e3d9d084"
        }
      ],
      "_links": [
        {
          "rel": "self"
        }
      ],
      "externalids": [
        {
          "system": "HQ1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "22222",
      "type": "PRODUCT_GROUP",
      "values": [
        {
          "showvalues": [
            "ObjectPosition"
          ],
          "value": "4",
          "attributeid": "gd4d20ffc-0374-4764-8b01-19b2e3d9d084"
        }
      ],
      "_links": [
        {
          "rel": "self"
        }
      ],
      "externalids": [
        {
          "system": "HQ2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Can somebody help me why this is not working?

```
$.data[?(@.externalids[?(@.system == 'HQ2')])].values
```

Basically, I need the `values` of all `externalids.system=='HQ2'`.

Comment: It seems JSONPath (all versions) don't accept nested/multiple conditions/predicates. You can get close enough to what you need if you can use JSONPath Plus.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but someone might be still interested, and as it turns out, it's actually doable!

1. Alright, as requested, using Goessner's implementation we could query the `values` from data objects that have a `externalids.system==HQ2` property like this:

   ```
   $.data[?( @.externalids && @.externalids.some(e => e.system=='HQ2') )].values
   ```

   This is kinda tricky: after filtering `externalids` a JS script evaluation is used to search the items using [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) (ES5) with an arrow function. Neat, ha? Test it online [on the Goessner tab](https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/).

---

2. In Jayway's JsonPath implementation we can use the same idea but need a a slightly different syntax:

   ```
   $.data[?(@.externalids && @..system contains 'HQ2')].values
   ```

   While this solution is very similar it is more prone to false positives since we are searching recursively for `system` properties. Use the same site to test it [on the Jayway tab](https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/).

---

3. And, as mentioned, if we use a more feature-rich implementation like [JSONPath-Plus](https://github.com/JSONPath-Plus/JSONPath) things become easier, e.g leveraging the `^` parent node operator:

   ```
   $..externalids[?(@.system==='HQ2')]^^^.values
   ```

   Get all `externalids` objects and filter the properties, then, go up the multiple times until we have objects under `data` for filtering the `values`. This can be tested online [here](https://jsonpath.com/).

So, if we are willing to apply certain workarounds this is very well attainable.